# Errors running cookbooks with chef-client

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

I'm trying to run a cookbook using chef-client by using "chef-apply default.rb" (where default.rb is the default recipe of the cookbook) but I keep getting the same error regardless of the cookbook I'm trying. Is what i'm doing incorrect? Is there another way to execute a single cookbook?

The errors I'm getting are:

```
[2016-07-20T11:00:57+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2016-07-20T11:00:57+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2016-07-20T11:00:57+00:00] FATAL: NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: yes, chef-apply is intended to run a single recipe, not a cookbook. Use chef-solo or chef-zero with a cookbook_path and runlist argument. See https://learn.chef.io

Comment: Is this why I'm getting the error?

Comment: According to my divination skills as you didn't show any recipe code, I would say you're trying to access `node['whatever']` attribute defined in the cookbook attribute file which is not loaded by `chef-apply` as its goal is to run self contained recipes only.

Answer (score 1):

As Tensibai mentioned, chef-apply is for training and sometimes one-off management scripts. It has no concept of "cookbooks". The likely issue is that chef-apply is not running the attributes files (because it can't) so expected default values aren't present in the recipe code.

tl;dr stop using `chef-apply`. You probably want `chef-solo`.

Comment: You mean Chef Zero, don't you? ;-) (aka. [Local Mode](https://docs.chef.io/ctl_chef_client.html#run-in-local-mode)

Comment: No, I mean `chef-solo`. Now that we have fixed solo to be Correct™ again, we're going back to the old labeling as it reduces user confusion.